# Getting array length of items with a specific attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I'm trying to get the percentage of items with the attribute of 'northwest' from a list of items in my JSON file. My idea was to get the length of the number of items with an attribute of 'Southeast', divide it by the total length of the array, multiply that by 100 and display the percentage.

Here's my JSON from leads.json

```
[{
"company": "Trasola",
"region": "Southwest", 
},
{
"company": "Hairport",
"region": "Southeast",
}]
```

JS

```
    <script>
  d3.json("data/leads.json", function(json){

    var length = $.map(json, function(d, i){ return i; }).length;
    var region = $.map(json, function(d, i){ return i.region === 'Southeast' }).length;

    console.log(region);
    console.log( (region/length)*100 );

  });

</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I think you're looking for `$.grep` in jQ or just `filter` in JS

Comment: length can be= json.length; and region is= json.filter(function(i){ return i.region === 'Southeast' }).length;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with all the libraries your using but the way I would do this in pure JS is as follows, simplifying it if I didn't need data on the other items.

```
var counts = function(myData) {
    var tot = 0;
    var map = {};

    myData.forEach(function(entry){
        tot++;
        if (map[entry.region]) {
            map[entry.region]++;
        } else {
            map[entry.region] = 1;
        }
    });

    return {total: tot, map: map}
};

var print = function (data) {
    var metaData = counts(data);
    var map = metaData.map;
    var prop;

    console.log(map);
    for (prop in map) {
        if (map.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            console.log('printing');
            console.log(prop);
            console.log(map[prop])
            console.log(map[prop]/metaData.total*100 + "%")
        }
    }
}

print(data);
```